# How to get a subscript in an integral bound in LaTeX?

Tags: border, integral, underscore

How to get a subscript like `v_0` in `\int_{v0}^v v dv` in LaTeX?

`\int_v_0^v v dv` gives an error

Comment: subscripts should _always_ be in braces.  `v_{0}` sometimes it works by chance without but: `\int_{v_{0}}^{v}`

Answer (score 1):

Is `$\int_{v_0}^v v^dv$` what you are after? Or, perhaps, `$\int_{v_0}^v v\,dv$`.

Comment: Thank you this is better. I am after $\int_{v_0}^v v\,dv$. However I would like to have the 0 somewhat more as underscore of the v. Is that possible?

Comment: @Frieke You can do `v^{}_{0}` if you want to move the zero down.

Comment: Thanks, this looks exactly as I want to have it!